# Send http request with encoded URI

Tags: citrus-framework

I m trying to send http request as follows, using citrus test framework http://www.citrusframework.org/

```
http().client(ENV).post("/xx/v1/ouxxtbound/tel%3A%2B94xxxxxxx")
                .header("Authorization", authorization)**strong text**
                .header("Accept", "application/json")
                .payload(send)
                .contentType("application/json");
```

its is passing a url encoded values, but when it encode again when sending  request by Citrus.as tel%253A%252B94xxxxxxx

Is there are way to send encoded URI correctly?

Comment: Have you tried to pass in the non-encoded URI to Citrus? I guess when Citrus and the underlying Http client is doing the encoding automatically you should be fine with adding the non encoded URI in your test code.

Comment: HI Christoph  ,Thanks for replying. Yes I have tried. When send the non-encoded URI it going as its. e.g tel:+94xxxxxxx(without encoding) . but need to send encoded URI for the sever.

Comment: Citrus using Rest template in spring which assume url encoding is necessary,seems like ":" and "+" taking as leagal url characters which ignoring encoding [link] (https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#exchange-java.lang.String-org.springframework.http.HttpMethod-org.springframework.http.HttpEntity-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object...-)

Answer (score 0):

Citrus uses the following method on the Spring RestTemplate

```
public <T> ResponseEntity<T> exchange(String url, HttpMethod method, HttpEntity<?> requestEntity, Class<T> responseType, Object... uriVariables) throws RestClientException {
    ...
}
```

The url is given as String value and Spring will automatically encode this value. When passing in some already encoded String the encoding is done twice. When using non-encoded String value the Spring RestTemplate applies uriVariables logic which is also causing errors.

Citrus should use some other method signature on the RestTemplate that uses the URL object instead of String value. As a temporary workaround you can use a custom RestTemplate subclass that overwrites the methods like this and automatically creates the URL object from String:

```
@Override
public <T> ResponseEntity<T> exchange(String url, HttpMethod method, HttpEntity<?> requestEntity, Class<T> responseType, Object... uriVariables) throws RestClientException {
    return super.exchange(URI.create(url), method, requestEntity, responseType);
}
```

You can add the custom RestTemplate subclass as Spring bean into the configuration and reference the bean on the Citrus client component by using the attribute *rest-template*.